# Corona simulator and newTextField

Tags: windows, sdk, lua, coronasdk

I think it a big limitation that you can't use "newTextField" in corona simulator, I actually need to build the app and install it on my device to see if it's working.

The following code for some reason not working for me, and I don't know how to debug it.
I simply want to save "players name"

```
local function textListener( event )

    if ( event.phase == "began" ) then

        -- user begins editing text field
        print( event.text )
        myGameSettings.playerName = event.text
        saveSettings()

    elseif ( event.phase == "ended" ) then

        -- text field loses focus
        myGameSettings.playerName = event.text
        saveSettings()

    elseif ( event.phase == "ended" or event.phase == "submitted" ) then

        myGameSettings.playerName = event.text
        saveSettings()
        -- do something with defaultField's text

    elseif ( event.phase == "editing" ) then

        print( event.newCharacters )
        print( event.oldText )
        print( event.startPosition )
        print( event.text )

    end
end

        local playerName = native.newTextField( centerX, display.contentCenterY-100, display.contentWidth, 50 )
        display.newText("Choose a name", 20, playerName.y-70, native.systemFont)

        playerName:addEventListener( "userInput", textListener )
```

Comment: Please describe specifically how it is not working (error message other observations).

Comment: nothing happens, from what it looks like "userInput" doesn't trigger the function

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be supported only in the Enterprise version.

Answer (score 0):

Is your problem that it isn't working in the Simulator?  Because they don't work on the Windows PC simulator but they work in the Mac simulator.  I develop on Mac and PC and can use them perfectly on Mac but not on PC.  I'm also no on the Enterprise edition but am on the free edition.

When I'm working on my PC how I debug is to hook my device up to the computer and print out the debug log as it will print any errors (I obviously can only use Android devices hooked up to my PC).

Answer (score 0):

First of all the native.newTextField does not display on window machine simulator. you need to build it on device for testing. But you can debug it on simulator though.
Use below code for debug on simulator.

Note: the textField area is not visible but when you click on it(Assuming text field position), will show you the textfield with blue rectangle border.

```
-- Hide the status bar
display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )

-- Set the background to white
display.setDefault( "background", 255, 255, 255 )

-- Require the widget & storyboard libraries
local widget = require( "widget" )

local function textListener( event )

    if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
        print( event.text )

    elseif ( event.phase == "ended" or event.phase == "submitted" ) then

        -- do something with defaultField's text
    elseif ( event.phase == "editing" ) then
         print("in move")
        print( event.newCharacters )
        print( event.oldText )
        print( event.startPosition )
        print( event.text )

    end
end

        local playerName = native.newTextField( 300, 300, 400, 50 )
        local a = display.newText("Choose a name", 20, playerName.y-70, native.systemFont)
        a.x=100
        a.y = playerName.y-70
        a:setTextColor(0,0,0)

        playerName:addEventListener( "userInput", textListener )
```

Comment: you are missing `function textListener (event)...` and as I wrote: "userInput" doesn't trigger the function.

Comment: The function textListener(event) is already there. Please check it on the above line. It did not came under code. So i apolosize

Comment: Have to tested the win_fix library?                                        Here is the reference:                                                http://code.coronalabs.com/code/native-textfields-and-textboxes-simulation-windows